# ios swift 3 xml parsing and displaying the data

Tags: ios, xml, swift3, par

I have tried to parse the xml data that i have . But i dont know what i am doing not able to print the data in screen as well as in console.

for my api :

```
Request-type : GET
Content-type : application/xml
url : www.example.com/data
```

here my actual structure xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<map>
    <data>
        <list>
            <item>
                <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
            <item>
                 <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
            <item>
                <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
            <item>
                <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
            <item>
                <map>
                    <answerChoice>
                        <list>
                            <item>option1</item>
                            <item>option2</item>
                            <item>option3</item>
                            <item>option4</item>
                        </list>
                    </answerChoice>
                    <assessmentID>ajhsdja</assessmentID>
                    <explanation>Explanations.</explanation>
                    <question>Which is ur name?</question>
                    <questionType>multiple</questionType>
                    <correctAnswer>option1</correctAnswer>
                </map>
            </item>
        </list>
    </data>
</map>
```

And my code that i tried :

```
     import UIKit

        class ViewController: UIViewController,XMLParserDelegate {

            var strXMLData:String = ""
            var currentElement:String = ""
            var passData:Bool=false
            var passName:Bool=false
            var parser = XMLParser()

            @IBOutlet var questNameData : UILabel! = nil
          @IBAction var button1 : UIButton! = nil
        @IBAction var button2 : UIButton! = nil
        @IBAction var button3 : UIButton! = nil
          @IBAction var button4 : UIButton! = nil

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                let url:String="http://exampe.com/exc"
                let urlToSend: URL = URL(string: url)!
                // Parse the XML
                parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: urlToSend)!
                parser.delegate = self

                let success:Bool = parser.parse()

                if success {
                    print("parse success!")




                } else {
                    print("parse failure!")
                }
            }

     func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {


        }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    }

     func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {

    }


}
```

Now the screen that i need to show is like this  :

```
 **QUESTION LABEL

  ANSWER 1
  ANSWER 2
  ANSWER 3
  ANSWER 4**
```

So i need to display each id question and the answer of that particular question..

I tried lot search in google not able to find the solution after that. Any help would be useful.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Better to convert xml to json via 3rd party library.
https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader
and then deal with json.

Comment: @hament miglani   how can i convert it from my code or that shoyld be a different part ?? like i need my xml url to convert or should i need to parse and then should i need to do convert to json.. if possible can u show me some code example ??

Comment: R u getting this XML in some api response?

Comment: this is my url,request type,content type ` Request-type : GET
Content-type : application/xml
url : www.example.com/data`    . if i put it in post man i will get the response same like i have posted in my question post

Comment: @hamentmiglani also i have posted the response what i am getting in my question post

Comment: After getting response, U need pass data format of response to XMLReader like that
do {
let second = try XMLReader.dictionary(forXMLData: response.data!, options: 1)
 }catch{
print("Some thing went wrong")
}

Comment: in my code i am getting `parse failure` in post many ia m getting the same response ...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `XML` response to `JSON` format like below steps:

First add this `XMLReader` Files in your project. You can download it from here : [github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader)

Now you have to get the XML Data from your API

Now create one function to read xml in json formate like,

```
func ReadXML(xml : String) {
    do {
        let dic = try? XMLReader.dictionary(forXMLString: xml)

         let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic! as [AnyHashable : Any], options: .prettyPrinted)

         let resDic = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json!, options: .allowFragments)

        print(resDic)
    } catch
    {
    }

}
```

you can use this function like,

```
    guard let xml = XML(data: YOUR XML DATA RESPONSE) else { return }

    self.ReadXML(xml: "\(xml)")
```

Or you can pass your URL like,

```
    let url:String="http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml"

    let urlToSend: URL = URL(string: url)!

    guard let xml = XML(contentsOf: urlToSend) else { return }
```

Hope this will be helpful to you. I am dealing like this currently.

Comment: thanks for ur solution. But currently i was not able to get the repose itself from my api. thats the problem now...thats why i have posted my code that i am using for parse the xml

Comment: So you dont know how to call api?

Comment: If your url is `GET` method and you are getting directly XML then you can directly pass that URL in my given solution. Please check it.

Comment: so if my url is like `www.example.com/data"  then `let url:String="www.example.com/data"

    let urlToSend: URL = URL(string: url)!

    guard let xml = XML(contentsOf: urlToSend) else { return }`

Comment: Yes, if you are getting Response like my given URL. check it in browser you will get xml data. so URL also having XML data in response

Comment: no, when i put my url its showing invalid content type, request type.. so i need to pass this both to get my data in browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143970/discussion-between-jigar-tarsariya-and-hybrid-dev).

Comment: XMLReader is 5 years old and written in ObjectiveC.